# How is the calculation of this push forward?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, pushforward

Hy

Please, i would like to know how calculate the push forward $(\chi_j k_j)_{*}(\varphi_j u)$ according to the fragment of paper that I put in the photo.

For me i have to use the push forward as a function in variables $(x,t)$ then
$(\chi_j k_j)_{*}(\varphi_j u)(x,t)= \varphi_j u ((\chi_j k_j)^{-1}(x,t)) =\varphi_j u (k_{j}^{-1}(x,t)\chi_{j}^{-1}(x,t))=\varphi_j u (k_{j}^{-1}(x,t) (\frac{x}{\langle t\rangle},t))$ but i think that something is wrong because $k_j$ is defined on $\mathbb R^n$ or some subset of it. And if i compose $k_{j}^{-1}\circ \chi_{j}^{-1}(x,t)$ do not have sense again, so how can i calculate this? Or how interpretate this push forward. Sorry by confusion, somebody can help me please?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: $\chi_j\kappa_j$ is a composition of functions. So what you’ve written for the inverse is not meaningful. You have to treat $\kappa_j^{-1}\chi_j^{-1}$ again as a composition, not as a product of functions.

Comment: Thank you @TedShifrin, can write as you suggestion and you tell me if i did well please?

Comment: Then, $k_{j}^{-1}(\chi_{j}^{-1}(x,t))=k_{j}^{-1}(\frac{x}{\langle t\rangle},t)$ but how can evaluate $k_{j}^{-1}$ if $(\frac{x}{\langle t\rangle},t)\in \mathbb R^{n+1}$ and $K_j:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$. I am still confuse, sorry

Comment: I don’t know what his notation with $\langle t\ rangle$ means, but you are right that the composition $\chi_j\kappa_j$ is not defined. So all the rest can’t make sense, unless one adds a $(\cdot,t)$.

Comment: Thank you again @TedShifrin

Comment: I was thinking is maybe they forgot put a tensor as $k_j\otimes 1$

Comment: Oops ... Yeah, that would do it.